# create one ul after last li

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my xslt:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::node()/child::*">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li onclick="final()">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my xml:-

```
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="m.xsl"?> 
    <root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
   <child_10 entity_id="10" value="Region" parent_id="1">
      <child_11 entity_id="11" value="ABC" parent_id="10">
        <child_12 entity_id="12" value="XYZ" parent_id="11">
          <child_13 entity_id="13" value="ABC123" parent_id="12"/>
        </child_12>
      </child_11>
  </child_10>
</child_1>
</root>
```

here is my output when executed above xslt code:-

```
 <ul>
    <li>Activities
    <ul>
        <li>Physical1
        <ul>
            <li>Cricket
            <ul><li onclick="final()">One Day</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here i want to output something like:-

```
<ul>
    <li>Activities
    <ul>
        <li>Physical1
        <ul>
            <li>Cricket
            <ul><li onclick="final()">One Day</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<ul id="last"></ul>
</ul>
```

question is:- i want to creat one `ul` after last `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jack Php: You have to add one line in your last template like below

```
<xsl:template match="*/*">
   <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
      <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*) = 'root'"><ul id="last"></ul></xsl:if>
   </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

You can find more [from here](http://ajaxandxml.blogspot.in/2007/11/xsl-function-to-find-parent-node-name.html) about `local-name(parent::*)`

Comment: i am edit my xml file when its multiple parent node its not work... check it out.... my edited.

Comment: I am getting created `<ul id="last"/>` at last but found that your edit XML file does not displays addition `<child_` elements like `Test1`, `Test At Abc` and so on what you added.

Comment: i am alss try this but its ok now one more thing how can add id="first" in first ul...

Comment: When I changed from `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[1]]" mode="item"/>` Then it printed all elements and at last `<ul id="last"/>`. Means that I changed value from [3] to [1] and it gives correct values. I also added some more elements for testing purpose and gives proper result.

Comment: no no not want to add new ul in top just add `first ul id="first"`

Comment: `<xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*) = 'root'"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">first</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>` add this before `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[1]]" mode="item"/>` and by that first `<ul>` will become `<ul id='first'>`

Comment: check it out i have create one new question its easy to understand my problem just view in my xml on them . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please change your last template with this one to get ul after last li:

```
  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
      <xsl:if test="self::*/parent::*/name() ='root'"><ul id="last"></ul></xsl:if>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete XSL is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::node()/child::*">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li onclick="final()">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
      <xsl:if test="self::*/parent::*/name() ='root'"><ul id="last"></ul></xsl:if>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Error loading stylesheet: XPath parse failure: Name or Nodetype test expected:

Comment: I think you have done something wrongly. Anyway, I have copied updated XSLT as well. Please have a look.

Comment: I just checked it once again, and it is workin fine in Oxygen with saxon parser.

Comment: let me know, how are you running it?

Comment: with above xml file link xslt stylesheet and run the xml file.

Comment: hey how to add id in first ul?